# Error adding cronjobs in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, cron

Until now, I have never attempted adding a crontask on my Mac. To my surprise, it threw an error..

```
[hayek@mac:/www/] 02:33:22 PM: crontab -e                                                                                                         1 .
crontab: no crontab for hayek - using an empty one
crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 1
```

How can I figure out why it's throwing that error?

I'm  running Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2

Comment: Are you using cron for a specific reason? On OS x it's largely been superseded by launchd

Comment: I wanted to use vnstat to track bandwidth usage, which requires a cronjob. I know I could use an alternative app, but it would still be useful to know how to make cron work on Mac, if at all possible.

Comment: Have you tried `crontab file` to install the table from an external file? Or using a different editor like `EDITOR=NANO crontab -e`?

Comment: @DanielBeck I use cron because it's much quicker to set up a new entry than launchd.

Comment: What does `crontab -l` show? Are there any other messages in `/var/log/cron.log` or `/var/log/system.log`?

Comment: @Lri good call! the editor was the issue. It looks like `vi` is the culprit, changing the editor to NANO or even `vim` got cron to work.

Comment: Related: [How do I edit crontab files with Vim when I get the error: 'temp file must be edited in place'?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/137/467)

Comment: Getting this on OS X 10.11 - found [this answer below](https://superuser.com/a/907889/90231) worked best.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In ~/.vimrc add:

```
    autocmd filetype crontab setlocal nobackup nowritebackup
```

Comment: great simple trick! works well for me.

Comment: This is the best answer and works well - much simpler than the one involving setting an env variable in the shell profile as well as editing `~/.vimrc`

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer since my own reply is no longer appropriate nor the most effective.

Comment: This works in Mac OS High Sierra too! Thanks for posting this

Comment: Can anyone please explain why this works?

Answer (score 44):

The issue turned out to be `vi` and nothing to do with cron. Doing `export EDITOR=vim` fixed it

Comment: Yes i understand you found the issue, and the solution is... what?

Comment: Try doing `export EDITOR=vim` then giving it a go.

Comment: Thanks @Hayek. Sorry for latency, i couldn't responsed as quickly as you did :P. However, running crontab with the almighty 'sudo' solved my problem.

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: I have just had the same issue. Setting `EDITOR=vim` did not fix it -- it just led me to a new error `crontab: temp file must be edited in place`.  I much prefer vim, however i edit cronjobs so infrequently that i'm happy enough doing it in `NANO` ... though if someone knows the fix, i'm very interested.

Comment: this is not answer at all. one should set 'nobackup nowritebackup' for vim! look at other answers below. IMHO augroup is best option.

Comment: This worked perfectly.

Comment: This worked for me and I was getting `$ crontab -e
crontab: no crontab for JayRizzo - using an empty one
crontab: subl -w: No such file or directory
crontab: "subl -w" exited with status 1`

Answer (score 35):

On a related issue, if you get the message:

```
crontab: temp file must be edited in place
```

Try:

1) Add to **.bash_profile**

```
alias crontab="VIM_CRONTAB=true crontab"
```

2) Add to **.vimrc**

```
if $VIM_CRONTAB == "true"
    set nobackup
    set nowritebackup
endif
```

Source: http://drawohara.com/post/6344279/crontab-temp-file-must-be-edited-in-place

Comment: This is the correct answer!!

Comment: This worked for me and I feel this should be the correct answer.

Comment: For csh or tcsh, use
`alias crontab "export VIM_CRONTAB=true; /usr/bin/crontab"`

Comment: I also think this is a better answer although the question from the OP does not mention the exact error @xgMz described. crontab does not appear to like the vim backup on write/save behavior so disabling it as described here just works.

Comment: I just had this issue with vim and cron on macOS Sierra. This is the correct answer!

Comment: I was able to use `:set nobackup nowritebackup` after starting `crontab -e` as an alternative to adding to adding the four lines to my `~/.vimrc`. No need to add an alias into my `~/.bashrc` either.

Answer (score 8):

Your editor on system variable EDITOR is **vi** and **vi** itsn't work.

Try:

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and followed the advice posted for creating the table:

```
crontab file
```

And that created the cron table, and then I was able to run

```
crontab -e
```

with vi as the default editor and had no problems. It is as if vi could not save the file, but once created, it could access it. This is consistent with being able to run:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

As a curiosity, the tables are stored in

```
/usr/lib/cron/tabs/UserName
```

which can only be read as sudo.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to diagnose this would be to create a fresh crontab with a simple entry like:

```
* * * * * /bin/date >> /tmp/cron_output
```

If that works then the issue is with the specific command you've added. Could you share it with us, and also share the results when you execute it directly from Terminal.app, rather than from a crontab?

Comment: Same error with the command you suggested. In terminal, `/bin/date` returns `Wed Nov 23 15:03:49 PST 2011` as expected.

Comment: OK, just seen your answer, which explains why you'd get the same error - just thought it might help to diagnose the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

cron is deprecated in favour of launchd.

[Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) is a great little tool for setting up launchd agents; it used to be free but appears to now be $3.

Wikipedia has a good [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) page describing all the keys and the launchctl tool you use to activate/deactivate them.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `au BufEnter /private/tmp/crontab.* setl backupcopy=yes` to vimrc fixed it for me.  See here:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_crontab

Answer (score -1):

I saw this same issue on OSX.  The answer is to run as root using the sudo command, e.g.:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

I got that idea from Gökhan Barış Aker above.

Comment: with `sudo` you are going to place cron jobs under root user. The cron files are different for your normal user and the root one.